# How to save a QImage with transparency?

Tags: c++, qt, transparency, qimage, alpha-transparency

I want to create a PNG image with transparency.

```
QImage image(dim, dim, QImage;;Format_ARGB32);
```

And I set the

```
qRgba(qRed, qGreen, qBlue, alpha)
```

But the alpha channel does not modify the transparency/opacity of the color, instead modify the intensity color (from white to color).

Thus, how can I set the transparency of the QImage (which I save on file)?

I have to use QImage, no other stuff.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect to **see** the transparency? Ordinary image viewers like photo viewers in Windows and Linux are painting the image on a **white** canvas. That's why the transparent pixels are being blended with white color. Look at the pictures below :

White background with no transparency on the circle:

[image: White background with no transparency on the circle]

The same circle with 50% opacity on white background:

[image]

The circle with transparency on a grid background:

[image]

That is why advanced image editors like Photoshop, are using such canvas as their default background.

Comment: Thank you. Now the behaviour of transparency it is more clear for me.

Comment: @valeriot90, Good, then it's a good idea to accept the answer and vote up. It's an equivalent to say "Thank you" but with less overhead ;)